# Showing current subcategory

Tags: loop, categories, children

I have problem.

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=events&posts_per_page=2&offset=1'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div>
<?php $children = get_categories('child_of=3');
foreach ($children as $child) {
    $child = get_category($child);
    echo $child->cat_name;
}; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I would like to show the current subcategory name from any parent category.

With this I only manage to output all the subcategory names from the specified parent...

I didn't use `the_category()` because it outputs the subcat names wrapped in a list and I would like them to be without any markup.

Comment: I don't understand your question. "I am within the Loop. I would like to show the current subcategory name from any parent category". What do you mean?

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: So you need to display all sub-categories from all parent categories. I can't understand your loop though. And why are you using `query_posts` here

Comment: I need to display current subcategory of that post from that specific parent category (Events). Please disregard QUERY_POSTS. I removed the bit where I call the title, the content and the meta from the posts

Comment: Ok, that makes sense

Comment: I ***strongly*** recommend against using `query_posts`, you must not use it, use `get_posts`, `pre_get_posts`, or `WP_Query` instead

Comment: Also can you rephrase your question a little? It's difficult to figure out what kind of template you're using this in, if you want to use it inside or outside the loop, please provide examples and additional context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a suspicion that you've fallen into a misunderstanding a lot of new users fall into, but rarely realise.

I suspect you have done this:

[image: a screenshot with the parent and child categories selected at the same time]

This is bad, and suggests a lack of understanding about how categories work. It will also cause issues in your code when your assumptions don't match the reality of things. But don't worry, everyone makes this mistake ( myself included ).

For example, we don't tell people that a house is also a building, they already know that houses are a type of building, and we don't have to mention to people that cats and dogs are animals for them to know, in the same way that you don't need to tell WordPress that your post is in the 'event' category if it's already in the sub category 'conference' or 'interest group', because it already knows that the 'event' category contains those.

What should have been done is this:

[image: a screenshot showing only the child category]

Here, even though I've only ticked the child category, any posts under child, will also appear inside the parent category archives, **because 'parent' contains 'child'**.

Child categories are not descendants of parent categories. Child categories are contained by parent categories.

So in your case, you grab the current category of the post, running into these issues:

- You mention the category the post is in, but a post can be in multiple categories, not a single category
- You assume the category you grabbed is the child category, but you ticked the parent category too, so it's probably the parent category you've grabbed, the child category is the next one
- You've assumed it's the child category, but it isn't, and now you're trying to find the parents parents category and failing because there isn't one.

What you need to do:

- Stop using `query_posts`, seriously, make your editor scream klingon at you when you type it, have a USB toy fire foam missiles at you, make your desktop wallpaper a pool of blood, ***never use it***. You have no excuses for using it. None.
- Stop checking every term up the whole hierarchy, just check the sub category you want. Categories contain all their sub categories, not just the ones that checked that specific box.
- Posts have multiple categories, even without the parent/subcategory thing, be careful
- foreach loops don't require a semicolon on the end

## So the code

This is you current code:

```
$children = get_categories('child_of=3');
foreach ($children as $child) {
    $child = get_category($child);
    echo $child->cat_name;
}
```

This will list out all the category names. In our example with the parent and child categories checked, it will print out this:

```
parentchild
```

First lets use a better function, that's more generic, and handle tags and custom taxonomies:

```
$categories = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), 'cat');
```

Then you have to check that the post actually has categories:

```
if(!empty($categories)){
```

And that it wasn't an error:

```
    if(!is_wp_error( $categories )){
```

So loop over your terms, lets put them in a nice list:

```
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($product_terms as $term){
```

Print them out:

```
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'product').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
```

and close the loop:

```
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

}
```

This gives you a full list of all the categories on a post. Now for the part you're having issues with. You only want to show sub categories. So we need to check if the category is a sub category before showing it, which you don't do.

So:

```
echo the term
```

Becomes:

```
if the term has no parent
    echo the term
```

You can check if a term has a parent by doing:

```
if ( $term->parent != 0 ) {
```

You also have a problem you're unaware of, what if I have 3 levels of categories rather than 2? What about sub-sub-categories? To handle that, perhaps you only want to show the bottom-most level, or only show sub categories and not sub-sub-categories. To do that you'll need to know if a category term has children.

You can also check if a term has children by doing:

```
if ( !empty( $term->children ) ) {
```

I leave the assembly of the final code as a task for the reader, but if you understand what has been said, you will understand what needs to be done ( and which lines to copy paste where ).

This won't fix users checking both categories, so you have to watch out for that. Ways of getting around that include preventing users from checking the parent category by using a custom radio box UI instead of the standard checkbox UI.

This is also why a category archive also contains all the posts in the sub categories.

## Glossary

- *Taxonomy* - a system of classifying things, e.g. category, tag, colour, caste, shape
- *Term* - a classifier in a taxonomy, e.g. 'red' is a term in the 'colour' taxonomy, 'pants' are a term in a 'clothing' taxonomy, 'cat' is a term in a 'animal' taxonomy, or 'pop' is a term in the 'music genre' taxonomy. Note that a term is not a thing itself, for example, pop songs belong in the 'pop' term of the 'music genre' taxonomy
- *Category and Tags* - two built in taxonomies that come with WordPress
- *Object* - something that fits into a taxonomy term, normally posts, but users and comments can also be placed into terms and taxonomies
  -

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you **should not** be using [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to run custom queries. From the codex itself

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like making use of pre_get_posts hook, for this purpose.

You should be using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for this custom query

```
$args = array(
   'category_name' => 'events',
   'posts_per_page' => 2,
   'offset' => 1
);

 $myquery = new WP_Query( $args );

 while ($myquery->have_posts()) : $myquery->the_post();

 <-----YOUR LOOP CONTENTS----->

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

**EDIT 1 & EDIT 2**

--SCRAPPED--

**EDIT 3**

Here is a work around of the code from [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories).

You first need to get the parent category's ID using [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$parentid = $categories[0]->category_parent;
```

This parent ID can then be passed back to `wp_list_categories()` to only show the child categories of that specific parent. If no child category exists, it will return the parent category name, otherwise if the parent have children, the child categories will be returned

Here is the complete function

```
<?php 
$taxonomy = 'category';

// get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
// separator between links
$separator = ', ';
$categories = get_the_category();
$parentid = $categories[0]->category_parent;

if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
    $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&child_of=' . $parentid . '&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // display post categories
    echo  $terms;
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried the code for displaying the subcategory. There is a dot in the last loop that produces an error. After cleaning that dot out, I see the result is the same: all the subcategories names are displayed. Third, is declaring $post_child_cat necessary? P.s. Thank you, I replaced the custom query bit.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Now the code outputs the categories, thank you, but the parent category is also shown...

Comment: I tried the code below EDIT2, but it still outputs parent and subcategory

Comment: I have another work around that should do the trick now. I hope EDIT 3 will do want you need.

Comment: Still no luck, but thank you! I have 3 posts on the homepage and all of them belong to "Events" category. Your solution works for posts that, besides "Events" category, are in "Conferences" subcategory, but not for posts belonging, besides "Events" category, to "Summer Schools" subcategory. I am almost sure it has to do with some strange default Wordpress alphabetic ordering for category names.

Comment: Are "Events" a parent category, or a taxonomy. Is is quite hard to understand that my code is not working for only "Events". Try pasting this in your code, check what it outputs on the "Events" posts.`$categories = get_the_category();
$parentid = $categories[0]->category_parent; echo $parentid;`

Comment: It should output you a numerical value, this is the ID of the parent category. It should not output a `0`. `0` means that there is no sub categories

Comment: I followed your indication. The post in "Summer Schools" outputs 0, the post in "Conferences" outputs 3. Anyway I believe it is interesting to take a look at the succession in which the categories are stored in the array: [link](http://i.imgur.com/GoRIt8P.png)

Comment: What is the relationship between "Summer Schools" and "Events". According to a `0` been returned, it shows both are parents that have no children.

Comment: Yeah, but actually: http://bit.ly/1tDMqyb

Comment: Ok, I'm dumbstruck here. "Summer Schools" is for some reason not been registered as a child of "Events". It is registers as a parent

Comment: Yeah it is a mystery for me as well.