# how to show the post category name

Tags: categories

I'm novice on wordpress development and I have this problem.

How can I show the post category name?

Example:

Post Title: Wordpress Rules!
Post author: Irwin R.
Post Date: 22/09/2014
Cat Name: Wordpress

I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
query_posts(array('cat' => 5, 'posts_per_page'=> 3, 'orderby' => 'ASC'));
while (have_posts()) { the_post(); 
?>    
<h3>Post Title: <?php the_title();?></h3>
<h3>Post Author: <?php the_author();?></h3>
<h3>Post Date: <?php the_date();?></h3>
<h3>Cat Name: // What function should I use here?</h3>
<?php       
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

I'll appreciate your help!

Comment: You will have to use `<?php the_category(', '); ?>` and as suggested below, never use `query_posts`. Use `WP_Query` instead.

Comment: Thanks Robert, it's works but i have another problem. I have one category and one subcategory, then the result shows  both categories and i want just the subcategory.

(e.g)

Cat Name: Development
SubCat name: Wordpress

I want to print just SubCat Name.

Comment: Please search the site I'm 99.99% sure that what you has been answered before.

Comment: You should have a read [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/145915/31545). This might help

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 1):

There is: [`the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category), which not only seems to be all to fittingly named.

Aside from that, don't use `query_posts`, as for the why take a look at those two threads:

- [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/22534)
- [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/22534)